# Updating App content on resume

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

this is going to be a noob question but i wasn't able to successfully google it.

In my windows phone app there's this method in App.xaml.cs

```
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

That is called when my App is brought back from the background. How can i have my main app page (main.xaml.cs) update itself with new data from the web when this method is beeing called. I only want it to happen when my main page is open but not when other pages are open

Can anyone give me a hint here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to update once your MainPage is opened, then why not to use `OnNavigatedTo` event of that Page?

Comment: this may be the solution thank you!